# how to send a form that contains another form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, c#-4.0

I have a form that contains another form.
the first form sends data to the action indicated in the beginform which the particular form it contains.
The second form ( contained in the first ) is a list that on change event,  exchange a picture, this works .
but the first form is not sent yet.

how can I do to submit the first form normaly and the second with the javascript on change ?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("VCreateCommande", "CCommande", new {id="formretouche"}, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    var imagedefaut = "";
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Retouchephoto</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group ilnblk">
    <div class="control-label col-md-2 fltleft">Type de retouche</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 fltleft">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("VCreateCommande", "CCommande", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Ttyperetouche.Idtyperetouche, new SelectList(
                      Model.Ttyperetouches, "Idtyperetouche", "libelle", ViewData["Idtyperetouche"]), new { @onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
        }        </div>
    <div class="fltleft imagemodele">
        @if (ViewData["Idtyperetouche"] != null)
        {
            foreach (var typeretouche in Model.Ttyperetouches)
            {
                if (typeretouche.Idtyperetouche.ToString() == ViewData["Idtyperetouche"].ToString())
                {
                    imagedefaut = typeretouche.SRCtyperetouche;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            imagedefaut = Model.Ttyperetouches.First().SRCtyperetouche;
        }
        <img src="@imagedefaut" />
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">Support papier</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Tretouche.Supportpapier, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tretouche.Supportpapier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">Quantité</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tretouche.Quantite, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tretouche.Quantite, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">Photo...</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tretouche.fichierphoto, new { type = "file" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @{
        String onclick = String.Format("Submit(this)",
            Html.Encode(ViewBag.returnUrl));
            }
            <input type="button" id="btnsubmitretouche" value="Ajouter1" onclick="@onclick" />
            <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid html5 to nest forms, see the [W3C HTML5 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element).

Comment: ok tks. 



I separated the two forms.
and I added in the form that performs submit a hidden input text that sends the necessary data

Comment: You're welcome, I hope that does the job. If my answer answers your question, I'd ask if you would make it the accepted answer :-)